# Question related to hardware, arduino etc

Tags: android, mobile, sim-card

Is there any possibility to get the number from the mobile sim card using any sensor ???
For example, if a person have a mobile phone in her hand and when the person pass from the gate we want to get the number of that sim card whose in her mobile phone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible!! You cannot get the number directly from the Simcard chip.
The encrypted data and some other data!

https://www.elprocus.com/how-sim-card-works/

You can read the above article to be more clear!

Answer (score 0):

No.  Telephone number isn't stored on a sensor, it is obtained from the network, and if you want to make it available to your application  you will need to have obtained permission to the telephony service, and you can then access it through a TelephonyManager object.

Comment: so what kind of data is in the sim card chip??
encrypted data ??

Comment: if we want to get the number using detector like of passing gate for humans can detect the metals !!

Comment: The second comment I can't make sense of, the first one...way off-topic but a SIM card does what it says on the tin - it is a subscriber identification module